# JSON WCF Service 404 on deployment server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, json, web-services, wcf-binding

I'm trying to deploy a WCF Service to my server, it works just the way I want it to locally. But on the server I get a 404 message.

This is what it looks like when I call my test method locally:

[Image of the wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAspj.png)

When I deploy it I can still successfully browse to:

www.my domain name.com/Service1.svc

but when I go to:

www.my domain name.com/Service1.svc/test

I get a 404 error. What could be causing this?
This is all relevant code:

**IService1.cs**

```
namespace HighscoreWebService
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string Test();
}
}
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
namespace HighscoreWebService
{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
}
```

**Part of Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="HighscoreWebService.Service1"
           behaviorConfiguration="jsonRestDefault">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http:/xxxxxx"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint name="jsonRestEndpoint"
              behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="HighscoreWebService.IService1">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonRestDefault">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTFriendly">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I suspect I made something wrong in the web.config. I'm very new to asp.net so it's possible I made any number of beginner mistakes. But because this works locally it could be  something wrong with the configuration of the server I guess. Or something in the web.config I need to do to adapt to the server configuration.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an "address" tag in your web.config endpoint.  Here is an example of what I have in my WCF testing project.  Though I would think that it should work how you have it.  This may sound silly too, but make sure the request you are making to the service is actually an HTTP `GET`.  Maybe post your client code too, if any of that doesnt work.

```
 <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="testBinding" contract="ASMXtoWCF.IWcf"   
       address="test" behaviorConfiguration="RestServiceBehavior">       
      </endpoint>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried adding address="test" but now when I navigate to it locally I get a message "endpoint not found"

Comment: can you post your client code you are using to get to the service?

Comment: I'm not using a client yet, trying to get it to work in the browser first. Like it works locally.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your merhodTest the behaviorto accept GET request (by default it accepts only POST). To do this add the WebInvoke behavior to it, for example by adding the following attribute **to your method implementation** (it's a behavior)

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

btw you can remove the *host* tag from your web config it is unecessary

Comment: But I have WebGet not WebInvoke? should I change? is there a difference?
Thanks