# WCF Service 404 error on browser

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

this might be very common question and asked many times but I troubleshooting this issue from the past 2 days.

I have created WCF service below:

**IStudentService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WcfStudentService
{
    // Defines IStudentService here
    [ServiceContract ]
    public interface IStudentService
    {       
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData();

    }
}
```

**StudentService.svc.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WcfStudentService
{
    // StudentService is the concrete implmentation of IStudentService.
    public class StudentService : IStudentService
    {
public string GetData()
        {
            return  "{ Result : " + "Success" + " }";
        }

    }
}
```

**Web.config(Updated):**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
        Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
        web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
        the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
        A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
        machine.config.comments usually located in 
        \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
    -->
    <configuration>
      <appSettings />
      <connectionStrings />
      <system.web>
        <!--
                Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
                symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
                affects performance, set this value to true only 
                during development.
            -->
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <!--
                The <authentication> section enables configuration 
                of the security authentication mode used by 
                ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
            -->
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <!--
                The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
                of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
                during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
                it enables developers to configure html error pages 
                to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
                <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
                <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
            </customErrors>
            -->
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
      </system.web>
      <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
          <webServices>
            <!--
                  Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
                  requireSSL="true" if appropriate.

              <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
              -->
            <!--
                  Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
                  profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
                  applications.

              <profileService enabled="true"
                              readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                              writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
              -->
            <!--
                  Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

              <roleService enabled="true"/>
              -->
          </webServices>
          <!--
            <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
            -->
        </scripting>
      </system.web.extensions>
      <!--
            The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
            Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
        -->
      <system.serviceModel>
          <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>  
            <!--Garvit: Commented below code-->
          <!--<service name="WcfStudentService.StudentService" behaviorConfiguration="WcfStudentService.StudentServiceBehavior">-->
              <service name="WcfStudentService.StudentService" behaviorConfiguration="jsonRestDefault">

                  <!--Garvit:Host Tag added-->
              <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                      <add baseAddress="http:/192.168.X.XXX"/>
                  </baseAddresses>
              </host>
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <!--<endpoint address=""   binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfStudentService.IStudentService">-->
              <!--Garvit: Added below endpoint and commented above-->
              <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfStudentService.IStudentService">

                    <!-- 
                  Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
                  identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
                  automatically.
              -->

            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="jsonRestDefault">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="RESTFriendly">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>      
      </system.serviceModel> 
 <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="StudentService.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>  
    </configuration>
```

The above service returns the result when I call it from WcfTestClient but when I browse my service URL on browser like(**192.168.X.XXX:8282/IStudentService.svc/GetData**) it throws 404 error.

I google and found these two below threads usefull:

[Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852543/json-wcf-service-404-on-deployment-server?rq=1)
[Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080360/wcf-service-404-error)

But still its not working. Please help.

**Any help**

Comment: Why don't you go for normal localhost address instead of the IP?

Comment: <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfStudentService.IStudentService">
Have a address attribute too in the endpoint config.

Comment: @Anurag: I am not using localhost because I want to access my service from the other systems as well within the same network which will not be possible in case if I will use localhost.

Comment: @Anurag: I am using <baseAddresses>
                      <add baseAddress="http:/192.168.X.XXX"/>
                  </baseAddresses>

Comment: I am using "webHttpBinding" not "wsHttpBinding" I have updated my web.config

Comment: try this.<add baseAddress="http:/192.168.X.XXX"/ProjectName/Service.svc>. When you give address as empty is endpoint config, the base address should be the url to the .svc file. Also, have you deployed your service to the server with the given IP?

Comment: @Anurag: No I have deployed the service on my local IIS with my system IP.

Comment: If you have deployed in your local IIS, then you will have to use localhost.Use as <add baseAddress="http:/localhost:8080/ProjectName/Service.svc>  I don't know much about how other systems in the same network will access it.

Comment: @Anurag:  <add baseAddress="http:/192.168.X.XXX:8282/WcfStudentService/StudentService.svc"/> Add this line but result is still 404.

Comment: @Garvit..see my above comment.

Comment: @Anurag: Add "<add baseAddress="http:/localhost:8282/WcfStudentService/StudentService.svc"/>" Now call "http://localhost:8282/IStudentService.svc/Getdata" Error: Bad Request

Comment: @GarvitGupta - "I am using "webHttpBinding" not "wsHttpBinding"" - Not according to your posted config.  Your endpoint is using `wsHttpBinding`.  It looks like you're trying to call the service as a RESTful service, but that won't work with `wsHttpBinding`, you need to use `webHttpBinding`.

Comment: @TIM - I am really sorry for this mistake, actually in my actual code I am using webHttpBinding, I forgot to update here in web.config.